# Constructor of derived class with base instance as parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    A() { printf("A::A()\n"); }
    A(const A &a) { printf("A::A(A &a)\n"); }
    A &operator=(const A &a) { printf("A::operator=\n"); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { printf("B:B()\n"); }
    B(const A &a) : A(a) { printf("B::B(A &a)\n"); }
    B &operator=(const B &b) { printf("B::operator=\n"); }
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(">> B b1\n");
    B b1;
    printf(">> b2 = b1\n");
    B b2 = b1;
    return 0;
}
```

Why the line `B b2 = b1` does not call the constructor `B::B(const A &a)` and instead calls `A::A(const A &a)`? How can I tell the compiler to do so?

Comment: Is there a typo, or am I missing something? You explicitly coded a B::operator=, which surely gets called during b2 = b1, but it does no actual assignment.

Comment: It is never called, that's why it has no code in it.

Answer (score 5):

Because it calls B::B(const B &a) which in turn calls A::A(const A &a). And you missed B::B(const B &a) in your class so you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because:

This:

```
B(const A &a)  
{ 
    printf("B::B(A &a)\n"); 
}
```

is not a copy constructor!

However, this:

```
B(const B &a)  
{ 
    printf("B::B(A &a)\n"); 
}
```

is a copy constructor.

With your version of copy constructor, you are ruining stack as well.

To prove you my point about stack corruption, you have got to try this:

> Notice that it will never print
>   **"Inside B::Print()"**

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { printf("A::A()\n"); }
    A(const A &a) 
    { 
        printf("A::A(A &a)\n"); 
    }
    A &operator=(const A &a) { printf("A::operator=\n"); }
    void print(){printf("Inside A::Print()\n"); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { printf("B:B()\n"); }
    B(const A &a)  
    { 
        printf("B::B(A &a)\n"); 
    }
    B &operator=(const B &b) { printf("B::operator=\n"); }

    void print(){printf("Inside B::Print()\n");}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(">> B b1\n");
    B b1;
    b1.print();
    printf(">> b2 = b1\n");
    B b2 = b1;
    b2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also by looking at your initialization list:
B(const A &a) : A(a)

I feel that most probably its a typo, I guess you meant to have:
B(const B &a) : A(a)

Comment: Though I compiled and ran your example, both lines are printed. B::B(const A&a) is not meant to be a copy constructor, but a way to construct B from any derived class from A, using solely the common data. Why do you say there will be stack corruption?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I guess I must have been wrong about the stack corruption. I said that earlier because I was in the debugging mode, and probably because of how implicitly A's copy constructor is called, my debugging would stop at that point.
Later I ran it without debugging it and it printed both print() funcs.